# Twitter bootstrap is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, responsive-design

Hi my problem is that the button doesn't work, I can't find where I'm wrong. Any help? Also I'm new in Twitter Bootstrap.`<button type="buttton" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">`

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="buttton" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Mitashki</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included both jQuery and BootstrapJS? See Example [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

Comment: I have only Bootstrap.js file. No jQuery file.

Comment: You need jQuery placed before Bootstrap then.

Comment: But in js folder have no jquery.js file...?

Comment: You need to place jQuery there or use a CDN to access it just link any other dependency. See the example I posted in my original comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Bootstrap , it's good if use basic template .

[Basic Template](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

And your problem : collapse navbars in Bootstrap uses bootstrap.js . And this file based on jQuery . So in bottom of your code you must add both files .

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to smack yourself for this. You should erase that extra "t" in

```
<button type="buttton"...
```

Comment: You mean '<button type="button">' ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here is your button]

Paspartu, the button that you are referring to is the sandwich that appears when your viewport is small enough. Try shrinking your browser until you see this.

Comment: Yes I know that, problem was no reaction when I'm clicking to the button

Answer (score 0):

`Buttton` should be `Button`...

```
<button type="buttton" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

should be

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

Also, if your button is not responsive, then you would need to add this to your header page:

```
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Add this **first** to your header. Your button that isn't responding needs JQUERY to work (and I took the links from W3schools for answering purposes)