# Why is my Bootstrap collapse navigation bar does not work?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  </head>

  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">

    <!--Start of the navbar section-->
    <nav id="my-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">      
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="navbar-brand">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!--End of the navbar section-->
  </body>
</html>
```

The code is working fine and I have read through the bootstrap manual and don't see any errors in my class names, but when I collapse my browser window to a phone view the button doesn't seems to work and it doesn't drop down the navbar as expected.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tvance929/gefpLodx ...  Heres a fiddle that you can start with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363492/twitter-bootstrap-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

There were a missing body tag, I replaced that with a div and works fine.
Here your code working as expected: http://www.codeply.com/go/dWnwMpejAH

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  </head>
<body>   <!-- changed here -->
  <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">

    <!--Start of the navbar section-->
    <nav id="my-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">      
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="navbar-brand">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!--End of the navbar section-->
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: @toddv updated, the body tag was out of the codeply code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add, `viewport meta`. Please add this inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

And yeah, you forgot to add `bootstrap-responsive.css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-responsive.css.min.css" />
```

**Working Output: http://output.jsbin.com/gelobacoxi**

Comment: Nope didn't fix the issue

Comment: @AlexMurray Check above answer.

Comment: @AlexMurray You need to add both Viewport Meta and `bootstrap-responsive.css`

Answer (score 0):

you need the following in your `<head>` tag, as per the boostrap **[get started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)** documentation:

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, pasting those scripts fixed the problem

Comment: what happens if we cannot use cdn? can we do a traditional registration of  jquery bootstrap scripts and still have the same impact?

Comment: @SpyrosSavvides: late reply. I am not sure what you mean by "traditional registration" but the alternative is to load the files — jquery + bootstrap locally (you've download to your folders)